# jQuery FullCalendar clientEvents() end time not defined

Tags: jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

When I call clientEvents() FullCalendar returns an array of events.  I want to then insert the results into a mySQL database with the Event title, start time, and end time however the end time gets saved as 0000-00-00 00:00:00.  Any idea why this is happening/how do you fix it?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?  Here's a start of one you could fork ....  https://jsfiddle.net/wbwkzvrp/

Answer (score 0):

Those time objects are created by MomentJS, that is a third-party library used by fullcalendar plugin, and are created following ISO8601 string format (aaaa-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.timezone). You can re-use those to render back your calendar.

If you need to save time as hh:mm:ss you can call :

```
start.hour()
start.minute()
start.second()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Saving the start time is working, it's the end time that is coming back undefined so I think that `end_time.hour()` will still be undefined but I will try it out.

Comment: Does clientEvent() return the propre endTime string ? When does that string is set to unedefined ?